# Sqlite INSERT INTO Error

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

I have this code which inserts into a table. This is the code:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Exercises Exercise, Weight WHERE ID = ?)VALUES (?,?)",(Exercise, Weight, ID,))
```

`Exercises` is the table name

`Exercise` and `Weight` are fields in the table

`ID` is a foreign key to another table

The error is `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Exercise": syntax error`

Thanks for any help

Comment: What were you trying to achieve with that WHERE clause?

Comment: What's that first `)` supposed to be doing? You probably want parens around the column list, but you definitely don't want half a parens around everything up to the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

The first syntax error is that `Exercises Exercise` is specifying a table name and an alias to be used later, and you're not allowed to do that in `INSERT` statements, only in `SELECT`.

But you probably didn't want `Exercise` to be a table alias, you wanted `Exercise, Weight` to be a column-list, specifying the columns you're going to give `VALUES` for later. That has to go inside parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO Exercises (Exercise, Weight) WHERE ID = ?)VALUES (?,?)
```

Meanwhile, you have an unmatched `)` later on, after the `WHERE` clause. That's another syntax error. I'm not sure if that was intended to mean anything, but if you just take it out, the statement is at least parseable into phrases:

```
INSERT INTO Exercises (Exercise, Weight) WHERE ID = ? VALUES (?,?)
```

But this still doesn't make any sense. What would a `WHERE` clause mean on `INSERT`?

And, even if it did make sense, you're passing arguments `(Exercise, Weight, ID)` but your placeholders are in a different order—ID, Exercise, Weight. That would be a pretty serious problem.

Anyway, taking a flying guess at what you want here:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Exercises (Exercise, Weight) VALUES (?,?)",
    (Exercise, Weight,))
ID = cursor.lastrowid
```

I'm not sure if that's what you were trying to do, but it is something sensible.

Or, alternatively, maybe you wanted to update an existing row:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Exercises SET Exercise=?, Weight=? WHERE ID=?",
    (Exercise, Weight, ID))
```

Meanwhile, you may want to read the docs on [`INSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) and [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statements. Although you may need a basic SQL tutorial refresher first.

Comment: Not to mention the bad variable naming.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hey, I just had to debug some code that got two named parameters backward and fixed it by passing (the equivalent of) `{'exercise': Weight, 'weight': Exercise}` as the args; by comparison, this one doesn't look so bad. :)

Comment: Hi thanks to all for the great replies. I know it wasn't the best code as I am just a beginner at this and it is for a school coursework project. I entered in the code above but it seems to create a new record in the table every time a new exercise and weight is added, this means that multiple MemberID's are being used by one user and so could not be referenced if the frame was closed and reopened. Is there a way to prevent this so that the ID is the same?

Comment: @DanielPatrick You need to explain exactly what you want to do, rather than making us guess. If you can't make it clear in words (or even if you can!), show a sequence of calls and what the expected results should be. Please edit that into the original question.

Comment: What I want to happen is that when the button is clicked the query inserts the exercise and weight into the table `Exercises` with the correct `ID`. For example if there are two exercises and two weights entered then they are inserted into the table with the same `ID`. Hopefully we have the same understanding.

Comment: @DanielPatrick What is "the correct ID"? Where does that ID come from? For that matter, what does the ID represent in your data model in the first place? Usually something called "ID" is a primary key, that's unique for each row, but it sounds like that's not what you mean by it.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` statements do not support `WHERE` clauses. Just specify an additional column `ID` in your `INSERT` statement, like so -

```
query = 'INSERT INTO Exercises(Exercise, Weight, ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)'
cur.execute(query, (exercise, weight, id_))
```

---

Alternatively, you may be looking for an `UPDATE` statement based on a supplied `ID` value:

```
query = '''
UPDATE Exercises
SET Exercise = ?, Weight = ?
WHERE ID = ?
'''

cur.execute(query, (exercise, weight, id_))
```

Comment: he probably wants `UPDATE` not `INSERT` in that case

Comment: Good guess on wanting to _store_ the ID; that's another possibility, which I didn't think of in my answer.